# Upgrading Umbraco 7.2.8 to 7.3.0

Tags: c#, upgrade, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I am currently working on Umbraco Upgrade. 
My Current version of `Umbraco is 7.2.8` and I want to upgrade it to `7.3.0.`
I have upgraded successfully but now i am trying to execute project it shows me below error :

[image]

Is there anything that have to be changed in database? Because i have upgraded via nuget.

Please help me out from this situation.

Answer (score 2):

1) In the web.config try to set the umbracoConfigurationStatus to emty, this will force a upgrade process:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="" />
```

2) In the Web.config check the umbracoDbDSN connectionstring. If you use a .sdf file check if the file exists. Else check the connection.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Umbraco.sdf;Flush Interval=1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <!-- Important: If you're upgrading Umbraco, do not clear the connection string / provider name during your web.config merge. -->
</connectionStrings>
```

3) Your database file is corrupted. restore the .sdf file from a backup, or try the repair tool. http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/ see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172420.aspx

Or the database file is locked or somethings by another process, restart the computer

Comment: No! Don't remove the connection string, it says so in the comment! `<!-- Important: If you're upgrading Umbraco, do not clear the connection string / provider name during your web.config merge. -->`